Building and network React-Native
I'm in trouble, making a project on react native with expo and in some files i sent POST and GET requests to my website, CORS resolved, strings to any origin been added. But it's only when i made the application. When i build and start application on my phone, view of application a little changed, but it not so worse. No one request didn't return correctly. Same problem in the web version, starting at the localhost. Console prints that error:
Access to fetch at 'https://*****' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.//
If i start application throgh expo qr-code then everything alright. Help me please)
Everything in details
